# Class Error - An object reference is required for the method

Tags: c#

I am currently studying C# and am trying to prepare for next weeks lessons which will be the introduction of classes and methods. To that end i have attempted to build a class called MaxBox which is meant to be a general utility class that I can store some general functions in like 'Displaying a String' or 'Play Again'. I've built my main file (Program) and my class file (MaxBox) and lines #23, #28 and #59 return the same general error 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'program.MaxBox.DisplayStr(string)'. #57 returns a similar error 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'program.MaxBox.PlayAgain()'

I'm a total newb really, and i'm wrestling with objects, I've done some research to get myself this far but I don't understand the language enough yet to be able to understand what the resources I've read are saying I guess to solve this error. Help and guidance is greatly appreciated. I'm still in my first weeks and really I know nothing.

Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading; // needed for close
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace a020_Breakcase_MeaningOfNames_C
{
class Program
{
    public void Play()
    {
        /*
         * Conditionals - Use switch/Case statement too:
         * Evaluate user data (name)
         * Return meaning of name evaluated
         * OR
         * Return 'Name not found' error message
         * Say goodbye
         */

        MaxBox.DisplayStr("What's in a name? Let's find out!");
        Console.Write("\n\n");

        do
        {
            MaxBox.DisplayStr("Enter Name: ");

            string uName = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            switch (uName)
            {
                case "doyle":
                    Console.WriteLine("Doyle means descendant of Dubhghalle");
                    break;
                case "fiona":
                    Console.WriteLine("Fiona is considered to be a Latinised form of the Gaelic word fionn, meaning \"white\", \"fair\".");
                    break;
                case "hunter":
                    Console.WriteLine("Hunter means to search with purpose");
                    break;
                case "liam":
                    Console.WriteLine("This name is a short form of the Irish name Uilliam (William) which is now use independently as a given name. As a Hebrew name, Liam means \"my people; I have a nation\".");
                    break;
                case "max":
                    Console.WriteLine("Short for of Maximilian, Maxwell, and the various name using it as a first syllable.");
                    break;
                case "portia":
                    Console.WriteLine("It is of Latin origin. Feminine form of a Roman clan name. Portia was used by Shakespeare as the name of a clever, determined young heroine in \"The Merchant of Venice\" who disguises herself as a lawyer to save her husband's life.");
                    break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry but I don't know the meaning of the name " + uName + ".");
                    break;
            }

        } while (MaxBox.PlayAgain());

        MaxBox.DisplayStr("C#eers!");
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program myProgram = new Program();
        myProgram.Play();

        Console.Read();
    }
}
}
```

My Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace a020_Breakcase_MeaningOfNames_C
{
class MaxBox
{
    /*
     * MaxBox is my general functions class
     * Contains 
     * DisplayStr() - Display the string given
     * PlayAgain() - If True, runs program again
     */

    public String uName;
    public String command;

    public void DisplayStr(String StrTxt)
    { Console.Write(StrTxt); }

    public Boolean PlayAgain()
    {
        Console.Write("\n\nDo you want to play again? (y)es or (n)o: ");
        String command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower().Trim();

        if (command == "y" || command == "yes") return true;
        return false;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Use str1.Equals(str2) to test string equality

Comment: You should instantiate `MaxBox` class, or change it to be static

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MaxBox's methods are not static, you need an instance of it.

```
MaxBox maxBox = new MaxBox();
```

at the beginning of your main class.  Then

```
maxBox.DisplayStr(....)
```

also, just to get you thinking, you can replace:

```
if (command == "y" || command == "yes") return true;
    return false;
```

with

```
return (command == "y" || command == "yes");
```

Comment: May seem like a minor detail, but it doesn't matter whether `MaxBox` is `static`, just that the members he's trying to access aren't.

Comment: What's a static? Why would he need an instance if it's not a static? If you're wondering - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx

Comment: Thank you - I'm so so so new to classes that i completely forgot to 'introduce' (substantiate?) my class to my program. Thank you. And thanks to everyone for all the great tips here. Last week i built a super simple class for my prior project and i'm trying again so when we hit classes i'll be ready as i've heard they're confusing - and they are but not AS confusing as they were last week - again super thanks!

Comment: Also - thanks for the suggest on how to return my command, that is very boss and gave me a lot to think about. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The methods `PlayAgain` and `DisplayStr` are instance methods on the type `MaxBox`.  In order to call them you need an instance of `MaxBox` on which to call them.  Right now you are trying to call them via the type name which only works for static methods

```
MaxBox.DisplayStr("hello world");  // wrong
MaxBox mb = new MaxBox();
mb.DisplayStr("hello world");  // right
```

It is possible to define methods such that you can invoke them from the type name.  But doing so requires that they be marked as `static`

```
class MaxBox {
  public static void DisplayStr2(string str){ ... }
}

MaxBox.DisplayStr2("hello world");  // right
```

Comment: Thank you for the help - very helpful comments all around and honestly very much appreciated.